# Server to server requests without a service account

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-api, google-calendar-api, service-accounts

**Short version:** Can my application authenticate itself with OAuth 2.0 without using a service account?

**Long version:** The issue I'm having with service accounts is that they can't be granted the same permissions as the original account that created them. Specifically, my company doesn't grant external accounts write permissions for security reasons. A service account is technically an application specific account, outside of the domain of the account that created it, and has more restricted access than an end-user account.

Is it possible for an application to authenticate itself as a user account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Service account is allowed to impersonate a user to get an access token.
See https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2ServiceAccount#formingclaimset Additional claims section.
https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-manager/wiki/GAM3OAuthServiceAccountSetup has description for how to configure it.

Comment: Thanks. However this allows my service account to impersonate as anyone within the company's domain.

Can I limit the service account to impersonate only as one specific user, or to limit the scope to one CalendarID?